# Match a string that does not contain a certain character sequence

Tags: .net, asp.net, regex, regex-negation

I'm trying to use regular expressions to match a string that does not contain the sequence of characters of a less than symbol (<) followed by a non space. Here are some examples

Valid - `"A new description."`
Valid - `"A < new description."`
Invalid - `"A <new description."`

I can't seem to find the right expression to get a match.  I'm using the Microsoft Regular Expression validator, so I need it to be a match and not use code to negate the match.

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Thanks,
Dale

Comment: What is the expression you are using now?

Comment: I've tried several. My last one was something like ^.*<(?!\S).*$ but it only finds a match if I have the less than symbol followed by a space. I need it to match if the less than symbol doesn't even exist in the string.

Comment: I am not sure why <\S(with a captial "S" does not work) it says hey if you can't find a space after your "<" then match it. When I did a test on the stuff you gave it worked.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@"^(?:[^<]+|<(?!\s))*$"
```

Doing a negative lookahead for space allows it to match if the last character in the string is "<".  Here's another way:

```
^(?!.*<\S).+$
```

The lookahead scans the whole string for a "<" immediately followed by a non-whitespace character. If it doesn't find one, the ".+" goes ahead and matches the string.

Comment: Oh, you guys rock! I can't believe I got so many possible answers so quickly. This expression ^(?!.*<\S).+$ gets the job done nicely.
Thanks Alan!

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you allow two things in your string:

1. Any character EXCEPT a `<`
2. A `<` followed by a space.

We can write that quite directly as:

```
/([^<]|(< ))+/
```

Comment: The parens around "< " are unnecessary, and extra parens in a regex add overhead. Also, I'd use `/^([^<]|< )+$/` to emphasize that the entire string must match. (RegularExpressionValidator adds an implicit ^...$, so you can get away without them in that specific case.)

Comment: This is real close. It doesn't match if the less than symbol is at the very end of the string, but I can live with that if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

```
var reg = new Regex(@"<(?!\s)");
string text = "it <matches";
string text2 = "it< doesn't match";

reg.Match(text);// <-- Match.Sucess == true
reg.Match(text2);// <-- Match.Sucess == false
```

Comment: what about "it doesn't match"?  I don't seem to get a match on that string. I need the string to be valid if it doesn't contain the < followed by a non space.

Comment: Unfortunately, that still doesn't find a match if the string does not contain the less than symbol at all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a negative look-ahead: "<(?! )"

Comment: that's the path I've been trying to go down, I just can't seem to get the syntax right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what your looking for.

```
Valid - "A new description."
Valid - "A < new description."
Invalid - "A <new description."



 Try this:   <\S
```

This looks for something that has a less then sign and has a space missing after it.

In this case it would match `"<n"`

Not sure how much it you want it to match though.